# Issues with TTN Data over Telegraf to InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, ttn

My data of my applications is being sent from the The Things Network to the MQTT server which I confirmed using mosquitto. I then configured Telegraf to scrape the data from the MQTT, which when ran, pushes:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> & "C:\Program Files\InfluxData\telegraf\telegraf-1.28.3\telegraf.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\InfluxData\telegraf\telegraf-1.28.3\updated_telegraf.conf"
>>
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z I! Loading config: C:\Program Files\InfluxData\telegraf\telegraf-1.28.3\updated_telegraf.conf
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.28.3 brought to you by InfluxData the makers of InfluxDB
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z I! Available plugins: 240 inputs, 9 aggregators, 29 processors, 24 parsers, 59 outputs, 5 secret-stores
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z I! Loaded inputs: cpu disk diskio kernel mem mqtt_consumer processes swap system
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z I! Loaded aggregators:
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z I! Loaded processors:
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z I! Loaded secretstores:
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z I! Loaded outputs: influxdb_v2
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z I! Tags enabled: host=A23748
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:10s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"A23748", Flush Interval:10s
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z W! [inputs.kernel] current platform is not supported
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z W! [inputs.processes] Current platform is not supported
2023-11-09T22:27:01Z I! [inputs.mqtt_consumer] Connected [tcp://nam1.cloud.thethings.network:1883]
```

This seems to indicate it is connected properly to TTN, however my data is not moving from Telegraf to InfluxDB even though it has the right API keys.

I tried to re do the config but it still is not moving the data through. The InfluxDB server should be accepting the data correct?